# WiFi networks not showing after deauth attack in Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, networkmanager, airodump-ng

I did a deauth attack to my own wifi.

After that I tried to connect wifi (in Kali Linux), but it showed network manager not running. I solved it by using `service NetworkManager restart`.

Then Network Manager opened, but it couldn't access my wifi networks (`unable to access "available networks"`).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'll use `wlan0` as interface name below. This should be replaced with the actual wireless interface name (such as `wlp1s0` or similar). It can be found in the list of interfaces using `ip -br link` and is most likely the interface with a `w` as first letter.

---

It appears that the `aireplay-ng` command used to send the [deauth attack](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=deauthentication) switches the wireless interface to monitor mode (aka `link/ieee802.11/radiotap`) but then fails to properly revert it to the usual managed mode. `NetworkManager` (and/or `wpa_supplicant`) then doesn't detect anymore a usable wireless interface. This can be checked by running concurrently `ip monitor link dev wlan0` and running as in the example in the previous link `aireplay-ng -0 1 -a 00:14:6C:7E:40:80 -c 00:0F:B5:34:30:30 wlan0` to see what happens.

First terminal:

```
$ ip monitor link dev wlan0
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,UP> 
    link/ether 
[...]
```

Second terminal, as *root* user:

```
# aireplay-ng -0 1 -a 00:14:6C:7E:40:80 -c 00:0F:B5:34:30:30 wlan0
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Device or resource busy
13:45:48  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 00:14:6C:7E:40:80) on channel 1
13:45:58  No such BSSID available.
#
```

At the same time in first terminal this happens:

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 1e:5a:93:39:ca:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST> 
    link/ieee802.11/radiotap 
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ieee802.11/radiotap 1e:5a:93:39:ca:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default 
    link/ieee802.11/radiotap 1e:5a:93:39:ca:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default 
    link/ieee802.11/radiotap 1e:5a:93:39:ca:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default 
    link/ieee802.11/radiotap 1e:5a:93:39:ca:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
```

In the end the interface switched from `link/ether` to `link/ieee802.11/radiotap` which is not usable as a managed Wifi connection.

---

The easiest to revert it to managed mode is to use the `iw` command which is the Linux low level command dedicated to Wifi interface. Its documentation isn't great yet. One of its help entries is for changing the type of the interface:

```
# iw help | grep 'set type'
    dev <devname> set type <type>
```

This has to be done when the interface is down.
So to revert to the usual managed mode, run these commands as *root* user:

```
ip link set wlan0 down
iw dev wlan0 set type managed
ip link set wlan0 up
```

Which gets in the first terminal:

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ieee802.11/radiotap 1e:5a:93:39:ca:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DORMANT group default 
    link/ether 1e:5a:93:39:ca:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 1e:5a:93:39:ca:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
```

The interface reverted to `link/ether`.

You might then have to restart again NetworkManager so it detects back a usable wireless interface if it didn't automatically.